# How to reduce my repeated jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

first post here at this great website!

I would like to reduce the amount of code for the following, espacially as there are more parts I need to add in the future - I'm sure there must be an easy way but I'm just not seeing it. Thanks for your help!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(function(){
            $('#iqdrive').click(
                    function(){
                                    $('#iqdrive-cont').show();
                    });
    });
    $(function(){
            $('#optiwave').click(
                    function(){
                                    $('#optiwave-cont').show();
                    });
    });     
    $(function(){
            $('#vario').click(
                    function(){

                                    $('#vario-cont').show();
                    });
    });     
    $(function(){
            $('#autostain').click(
                    function(){
                                    $('#autostain-cont').show();
                    });
    });     
    $(function(){
            $('#autoload').click(
                    function(){
                                    $('#autoload-cont').show();
                    });

    });
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to nest `document.ready` functions (all the `$(function() {` are redundant as it is equivalent to `document.ready`). And to simplify your code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#iqdrive, #optiwave, #vario, #autostain, #autoload').click(function() {
        $('#' + this.id + '-cont').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Cool, thanks - I knew it is horribly bloated which is why I came here - this has cleared a few things up :)

Answer (score 0):

All of the internal `$(function())` calls are unnecessary, since `$(function())` is an alias for `$(document).ready(function())`. Your example shows a lot of repetition of the same sort of task; that's very easy to consolidate.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#iqdrive, #optiwave, #vario, #autostain, #autoload').click(function(){
    $($(this).attr("id") + "-cont").show();
  });
});
```

What that does is register for clicks on elements with any of those IDs, and on click, gets the ID of the clicked element, appends `-cont`, and uses that as a selector to get a set of elements to show.